# PHP: Simple HTML DOM Parser - how to get the element which has certain tag name?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

In PHP I'm using the Simple HTML DOM Parser class.

I have a HTML file which has multiple and diferents tags.

In this HTML there is an element like this:

```
<a name="10418"><b>&nbsp;Hospitalist (Family Practitioner)</b></a>
```

So I would like to find that '**a**' element with has  **name="10418"**

I've tried this with no luck, because I only want to get that string.

```
  $html_object = str_get_html($url);
  $html_object=$html_object->find('a');
  foreach ($html_object as $o) {
            $a= $o->find("b");
            echo $a[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$anchor = $html_object->find('a[name=10418]', 0);
echo $anchor->plaintext;
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vxf-gb5)</kbd>

Comment: that gives me this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @user3002293, it works fine, check the demo... Are you sure your html code contains that anchor ? (give me the link to check if possible)

Comment: could you try this please? http://pastebin.com/qJXQbvyh I don't know why my code is getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Try another library called [Tag Parse](https://github.com/yangxikun/tag-parse).It's simple and efficient.

```
$dom = new TagParse\TagDomRoot($html);
$a = $dom->find('a[name="10418"]');
```

I think it's fast and cost less memory than simple_html_dom.